# Adsense gets injected in my site

Tags: magento, adsense, code-injection

We got some clients that are complaining they got some "strange advertisements" on top of our Magento webshop. The screenshots they sent through indicate these are clearly Adsense advertisements, but we don't participate in the Adsense programme. So I guess somebody/something is injecting these codes.

The strangest thing is: I have never seen this behaviour in any browser, and people I know that I asked haven't too. But apparently there are people who do see it :|

We asked them to send us through the source code of the page, and it appears the adsense is located ABOVE the doctype rule ...

```
center><script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- de -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-7837806915816060"
data-ad-slot="1724932034"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</br>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- uk -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-7837806915816060"
data-ad-slot="8650939636"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script> 
</br>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- US -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-7837806915816060"
data-ad-slot="1127672839"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script> </center><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Anybody who knows what could be going on?
Probably I could hide these by setting .adsbygoogle to display:none but of course I want to tackle the real problem and not just camouflage it :)

Thanks

Comment: Looks like attack.
Post the adsence code of Google account to admin of Google Adsense to block the account. Code must be in infected files like index.php. look to the source code of index.php and eventually remove the injected code.
Change all passwords, FTP, admin, etc...

Comment: Hi Martin,

Thanks for your reply.
I scanned all the files for "adsbygoogle" but didn't get any results back. (also index.php doesn't seem to be affected). Maybe it's in some way encoded?

The oddest thing too is that I've never seen this code injected on my computer. On every browser. So I wondered maybe this was something client side.

Comment: Yes it is possible. It can be on the client side only. If is only one. In each case make described steps to block and ban this account to help others.

Comment: In fact we had multiple customers reporting this, so I guess I'll have to dig further into the code. This is crap...

Comment: Same problem, for one of our customers... Magento version?

Comment: We ended up using the services of "Sucuri Security".
After that the injected code was detected in no time. Not that cheap, but the site keeps clean now. (Client site Magento is rather old, so quite vulnerable)

Answer (score 0):

Malicious codes are injected into the core_config_data table in the database. Use the following queries to remove the entries.

```
select * from core_config_data where value like "%googlesyndication%";
delete from core_config_data where config_id = {the config_id};
```

Hope this helps.